# How to change array_agg() to return empty array on empty input in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, array

I am trying to write a PostgreSQL array_agg() variant that returns the empty array `'{}'` instead of NULL. Trying to avoid the performance hit of custom aggregate functions with `CREATE AGGRGATE`, I tried to re-use the built-in `array_agg_transfn` and `array_agg_finalfn`. Starting from the code [example in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xaggr.html#XAGGR-POLYMORPHIC-AGGREGATES), an initial version similar to array_agg works (as DB superuser):

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_z (anynonarray)
(
    sfunc = array_agg_transfn,
    stype = internal,
    finalfunc = array_agg_finalfn,
    finalfunc_extra
);
```

And it returns NULL on empty input as expected:

```
=> SELECT array_agg_z(i) IS NULL FROM (SELECT 0 WHERE 1 = 2) t(i);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Now, to change `array_agg_z()` to return empty array on empty input, I attempted to set the `initcond` to `'{}'` as follows:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_z (anynonarray)
(
    sfunc = array_agg_transfn,
    stype = internal,
    finalfunc = array_agg_finalfn,
    initcond = '{}',
    finalfunc_extra
);
```

Now it's giving an error:

```
=> SELECT array_agg_z(i) IS NULL FROM (SELECT 0 WHERE 1 = 2) t(i);
ERROR:  cannot accept a value of type internal
```

*How to work around this?*

Or do I have to hack the C source code related to `array_agg()` to make this variant?

By the way, this is with PostgreSQL 12.

Comment: Why don't you use `coalesce(array_agg(...), '{}')`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Indeed, that works too. I am just trying to avoid doing that (coalescing to different kinds of zeros) everywhere, if this is possible like custom aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I wrote a custom array_agg a number of weeks ago, and I can boil out what you seem to need.

First, we will put together an accumulator function, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_agg_z_accum(anyarray, anynonarray)
RETURNS anyarray AS $$
BEGIN
    IF $1 IS NULL THEN
        RETURN ARRAY[$2];
    ELSE
        RETURN array_append($1, $2);
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then use it in our aggregate, replacing `anynonarray` with `anyelement`:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_z(anyelement) (
  SFUNC = array_agg_mult_accum,
  STYPE = anyarray,
  INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

Finally:

```
SELECT array_agg_z(i) IS NULL FROM (SELECT 0 WHERE 1 = 2) t(i);
```

Produces:

| ?column? |
| --- |
| FALSE |